# When can we use "the" with comparatives?

Tags: comparative

I have already found in a book this rule:

> The comparative structure includes *the* only when the comparative takes a noun position, example:
>
> > I like the smaller of the two.

May you explain me this rule and give more examples? Because I do not understand.

Comment: *the smaller = the smaller **one*** i.e. - ***the one which is smaller*** (than all other relevant ones). It's not syntactically necessary to explicitly specify ***of the two*** in your example. For example, *Here are two slices of pie. I'll have the smaller [one], and you can have the larger*.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, if the comparative is used as either the subject or object of the sentence, it's used as a noun - i.e. if you can remove that part of the sentence and get it by asking "Who" or "What".

In this case we have:

```
Q: Who/What do I like? 
A: The smaller of the two.
```

An example where this cannot be used:

```
The first book is smaller.
```

If you would to remove "smaller" form the sentence and ask:

```
Q: Who/What is the first book?
A: Smaller.
```

"Who" doesn't make any sense, while "What" makes some sense but it's used in a different way. `Smaller` describes the book, not itself. If the answer was `the smaller` it would not fully answer the question, because it would just raise another - `The smaller of what?`. The answer needs to have meaning by itself.

Side not on this example. If there was a text before that clearly defines what `the smaller` is, we could use it. E.g.:

```
The first book is the smaller of the two. I am going to read the smaller.
```

Here `the smaller` clearly means the first book.

Hope this clarifies things a bit, articles can be tricky, you learn them mostly through exposure to the language. :)